# Comunication to from child process hanging on read in C

Tags: c, fork, file-descriptor, dup2

I'm trying to communicate with an external program which, if executed, will run a terminal interface.
Normally I'll have to provide some inputs (e.g. "1+1") and then read the output of the program (e.g. "2").
Since I need a two-way communication I wasn't able to use popen().

My problem is the following:

Whenever I have a part of the code that asks for inputs, for example containing `std::cin >> input` I run into the same issue, the `read` command never exits.

Here I wrote a minimal example, all the child process does is reading the input and repeating it.

When I try to run this code what happens is that I see the first print "Parent says:" and I can provide the input and send it using `write`. However, when I try to call again the `read()` function the see the outcome, it never exit.

I've noticed that if I close the pipe that goes from the parent to the child (`fd_p2c[1]`), then I can read successfully.
This is clearly not what I want, since in my application I'd like to keep both communications open.

Any suggestions on what could be done to fix this problem?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int status, buf_length;

  // Input and output
  char buf[256];
  char msg[256];
  char child_read[256];

  int fd_c2p[2]; // file descriptor pipe child -> parent
  int fd_p2c[2]; // file descriptor pipe parent -> child

  pipe(fd_c2p);
  pipe(fd_p2c);

  // Spawn a new process with pid
  pid_t pid = fork(); // Fork process

  if (pid == 0) {
    // Child

    // Close the unused end of the pipe
    if (close(fd_p2c[1]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[0]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // Set the comunication
    if (dup2(fd_p2c[0], STDIN_FILENO) != 0 ||
        dup2(fd_c2p[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != 1 ||
        dup2(fd_c2p[1], STDERR_FILENO) != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to duplicate the end of the pipes\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // These two pipe ends are not needed anymore
    if (close(fd_p2c[0]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[1]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // ask kernel to deliver SIGTERM in case the parent dies
    prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);

    // Moch program
    while (1) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Parent says: ");
      fflush(stdout);
      scanf("%s", child_read);
      fprintf(stdout, " >> Child repeat: %s\n", child_read);
      fflush(stdout);
    }
    exit(1);
  } else {
    // Parent

    // These two pipe ends are not needed anymore
    if (close(fd_p2c[0]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[1]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  // Read output and send input
  while (1) {
    // Read from child
    while (buf_length = read(fd_c2p[0], buf, sizeof(buf) - 1)) {
      buf[buf_length] = '\0';
      printf("%s", buf);
    }

    // Enter message to send
    scanf("%s", msg);
    if (strcmp(msg, "exit") == 0)
      break;

    // Send to child
    write(fd_p2c[1], msg, strlen(msg));
    //close(fd_p2c[1]);
  }

  printf("KILL");
  kill(pid, SIGKILL); // send SIGKILL signal to the child process
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

Comment: The loop `while (buf_length = read(fd_c2p[0], buf, sizeof(buf) - 1))` have one fatal flaw: If `read` fails you will not detect it, and immediately write out of bounds of the array `buf`.

Comment: What kind of application are you developing?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is extracting information from a set of differential equations in order to make predictions on some scattering processes in particle physics. All the operations are performed by a c++ code while a outsource the algebraic manipulations to an external program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I somehow thought that negative numbers would be interpreted as false.... which of course they are not.

Comment: @snaporaz: several colleagues from  http://www-list.cea.fr/ could be interested ..... And even more from https://www.cea.fr/english (my current employer), e.g. https://www.cea.fr/english/Pages/research-areas/matter-and-universe.aspx - and obviously scientists from https://home.cern/

Comment: regarding:  `dup2(fd_c2p[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != 1 ||
        dup2(fd_c2p[1], STDERR_FILENO) != 2) {` this seems to be an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is in the child-process with:

```
scanf("%s", child_read);
```

With the `%s` format there's only three things that will stop `scanf` from waiting for more input:

1. Error
2. End of file
3. Space

Assuming nothing goes wrong, there will be no errors. And since the parent process keeps the pipe open there will be no end of file. And since the parent process writes only what it itself reads with `scanf("%s", ...)` there will be no spaces in the data sent.

All in all, the child process will wait indefinitely for `scanf` to return, which it never will.

Comment: The child process is written like this only to mimic the behaviour I have when I execute the actual program in the child process. The problem is that I'm never able to reach the write function because the read hangs forever (once the child asks for input).
I think is a problem with the read since the pipe remains open ( as it should). 

The question is then: Is there a way to check if the file descriptor I want to read from is empty?

Comment: @Snaporaz You could make the descriptors *non-blocking*. Then `read` will return with error `EWOULDBLOCK` if there's nothing to read.

Comment: This seems to do the trick when combined with a way to synchronize the communication. I'll post the updated code with all the information.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a two-ways communication, you could use some [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket, or *several* [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s, or some [fifo(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html).

You could use some [JSONRPC](https://www.jsonrpc.org/) library. Or [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) (perhaps [ONC/RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call)/XDR) or [ASN/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) for binary communication between heterogeneous computers in a data center, or [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). If you can use some [supercomputer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer), it probably has proprietary libraries to ease message passing between processes running on different nodes.

Consider using [OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/).

> I'm trying to communicate with an external program which, if executed, will run a terminal interface.

Maybe you then need some [pty(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html) with [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) ? Then take inspiration from the source code of `xterm` or of `rxvt`

You probably need some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) before attempting a [read(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) (or [recv(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html)...) or a [write(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (or [send(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html))

You could find open source libraries (e.g. [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/), [libev](https://libev.org/), ...) to help you, and you certainly should study for inspiration their source code.

Comment: I'll definitely look into these tools. I wanted to directly use pipes and child process since I thought it was going to be more efficient. This communication will end up having to parse several MBs of instructions and results back and forth millions of times, so efficiency is key.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call a *word* what `scanf("%s")` is able to extract.
This is a contiguous sequence of characters that are not separators (space, tab, new-line...).

The (redirected) standard input of the child reads a *word* with `scanf("%s", child_read);`.
This *word* is known as ended when a separator is read or EOF is reached.
In the parent, `write(fd_p2c[1], msg, strlen(msg));` sends a *word* (and nothing more right after it) because `msg` is extracted just before as a *word*.

Note that when you input a *word* with the keyboard, you also hit the enter key which sends the new-line separator in the standard input. At this time, the terminal makes this line available to `scanf()`, the *word* is known as ended and the separator is ignored (in this specific situation, but we could obtain it with `fgetc()`).

For example, if in the standard input of the parent we input `"abc\n"`,
the parent obtains the word `"abc"` which is sent as is to the child.
Then the child receives a word starting with `"abc"` but not ended yet: `scanf("%s")` is still waiting some other characters after `c` to make this word longer or a separator or EOF to detect the end of this word.

You can for example send a separator after this word.

```
// Send to child
write(fd_p2c[1], msg, strlen(msg));
char lf='\n';
write(fd_p2c[1], &lf, 1);
```

Or maybe it's better to rely on `fgets()` (instead of `scanf("%s")`) to obtain a line (not just a *word*) both in the child and the parent.

By the way, the `while/read` in the parent looks weird to me.
I would do something like this.

```
// Read from child
buf_length = (int)read(fd_c2p[0], buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
if (buf_length <= 0) {
  break;
}
```

Comment: Indeed I need to end the sent message, nice catch! I'm still left with the reading problem, somehow I should check it the file descriptor I'm reading from is empty and in that case, I shouldn't try to read unless I'm expecting additional output (e.g I know that before asking for input the program prints ">").

Answer (score 1):

Since in general, I wouldn't know the length of the message in that I need to read form `fd_c2p`, I need to create a look that listens to the pipe till its empty.

To do it is necessary to add the `O_NONBLOCK` to the file descriptor in the parent as suggested by @some-programmer-dude:

```c
    // Parent

    // close unused pipe ends
    // These two pipe ends are not needed anymore
    if (close(fd_p2c[0]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[1]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // Add O_NONBLOCK the the fd that reads from the child
    int c2p_flags = fcntl(fd_c2p[0], F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fd_c2p[0], F_SETFL, c2p_flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now, when I read the output of the child from the file descriptor `fd_c2p[0]`, it returns an error whenever we attempt to read from an empty file.
Reading the error code in `errno` should match `EWOULDBLOCK`.

To know when to stop to read from `fd_c2p[0]` some knowledge on the output is needed.
This particular reading should stop when the last character of the line when it reaches `EWOULDBLOCK` and the previous message ended with `:`.

```c
    // Read from child
    end_of_message = false;
    while (1) {
      buf_length = read(fd_c2p[0], buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
      if (buf_length == -1)
      {
        if (end_of_message && errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
          break;
        else if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
          continue;
        else {
          fprintf(stderr, "reading from pd_c2p returned an error different "
                          "from `EWOULDBLOCK'\n");
          exit(errno);
        }
      }
      buf[buf_length] = '\0';
      printf("%s", buf);
      end_of_message = buf[buf_length - 1] == ':';
    }
```

This patch solves the problem of reading from the file when one is not sure about how many lines are there before the program asks for inputs.

It should also be safe when the message contains `:` at any position. To test it, one can reduce the different buffers to a smaller size (e.g. from 256 to 1).

It was also pointed out from by @prog-fh, that in principle one would like to have inputs that contains spaces as well. To accomodate can use `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```c
   // Enter message and send it over to the chid process
    while (fgets(msg, 256, stdin) != NULL) {
      if (msg[strlen(msg)] == '\0')
        write(fd_p2c[1], msg, strlen(msg));
      else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encounter while reading input\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      if (msg[strlen(msg) - 1] == '\n')
        break;
      else
        continue;
    }
```

Among the advantages of using `fgets` there is the fact that the string will keep the newline `\n` at the end, meaning that there is no need to push an extra character to the write buffer once we are done reading the message.

The complete code is then

```c
#include <cerrno>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int status, buf_length;
  bool end_of_message = false;

  int fd_c2p[2]; // file descriptor pipe child -> parent
  int fd_p2c[2]; // file descriptor pipe parent -> child

  // Input and output
  char buf[256];
  char msg[256];
  char child_read[256];

  // We need two pipes if we want a two way comunication.
  pipe(fd_c2p);
  pipe(fd_p2c);

  // Spawn a new process with pid
  pid_t pid = fork(); // Fork process

  if (pid == 0) {
    // Child

    // Close the unused end of the pipe
    if (close(fd_p2c[1]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[0]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // Set the comunications
    if (dup2(fd_p2c[0], STDIN_FILENO) != 0 ||
        dup2(fd_c2p[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != 1 ||
        dup2(fd_c2p[1], STDERR_FILENO) != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to duplicate the end of the pipes\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // These two pipe ends are not needed anymore
    if (close(fd_p2c[0]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[1]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // ask kernel to deliver SIGTERM in case the parent dies
    prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);

    // Moch Program
    while (1) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Parent says:");
      fflush(stdout);

      fgets(child_read, 256, stdin);
      fprintf(stdout, " >> Child repeat: %s", child_read);
      while (child_read[strlen(child_read) - 1] != '\n') {
        fgets(child_read, 256, stdin);
        fprintf(stdout, " >> Child repeat: %s", child_read);
      }
      fflush(stdout);
    }

    // Nothing below this line should be executed by child process.
    // If so, it means that thera has beed a problem so lets exit:
    exit(1);
  } else {
    // Parent

    // close unused pipe ends
    // These two pipe ends are not needed anymore
    if (close(fd_p2c[0]) != 0 || close(fd_c2p[1]) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Faild to close unused end of pipe\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    // Add O_NONBLOCK the the fd that reads from the child
    int c2p_flags = fcntl(fd_c2p[0], F_GETFL);
    fcntl(fd_c2p[0], F_SETFL, c2p_flags | O_NONBLOCK);
  }

  // Now, you can write to fd_p2c[1] and read from fd_c2p[0] :
  while (1) {

    // Read from child
    end_of_message = false;
    while (1) {
      buf_length = read(fd_c2p[0], buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
      if (buf_length == -1)
      {
        if (end_of_message && errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
          break;
        else if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
          continue;
        else {
          fprintf(stderr, "reading from pd_c2p returned an error different "
                          "from `EWOULDBLOCK'\n");
          exit(errno);
        }
      }
      buf[buf_length] = '\0';
      printf("%s", buf);
      end_of_message = buf[buf_length - 1] == ':';
    }

    // Enter message and send it over to the chid process
    while (fgets(msg, 256, stdin) != NULL) {
      if (msg[strlen(msg)] == '\0')
        write(fd_p2c[1], msg, strlen(msg));
      else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encounter while reading input\n");
        exit(1);
      }

      if (msg[strlen(msg) - 1] == '\n')
        break;
      else
        continue;
    }

    // Check if the user wants to exit the program
    if (strcmp(msg, "exit\n") == 0)
      break;
  }

  printf("KILL");
  kill(pid, SIGKILL); // send SIGKILL signal to the child process
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```